# Python Multiprocessing failing when using module import

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am struggling with the python multiprocessing module, when using the 'spawn' method.
If i just run a file like the following directly, everything works fine:

main_process.py:

```py
import multiprocessing as _mp
import os
mp = _mp.get_context('spawn')

class Process(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(os.getppid(), os.getpid(), "Init Process")

    def run(self):
        print(os.getppid(), os.getpid(), "Hello World!")


def main_function():
    print(os.getppid(), os.getpid(), 'main')
    process_1 = Process()
    process_1.start()
    process_1.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_function()
```

I get the output as expected:

```
23337 25062 main
23337 25062 Init Process
25062 25067 Hello World!
```

If on the other hand, I import the `main_function()` from a second file and try to run it like this

```py
from main_process import main_function
main_function()
```

I get the following output:

```
23337 25104 main
23337 25104 Init Process
25104 25106 main
25104 25106 Init Process
RuntimeError: ...
```

It looks like the created `Process` instance will rerun the `main_function()` again, even though its only supposed to run the body of its `run()` function, or at least that is what I would expect.
Using the 'fork' method to start the process, it works as intended.

Why is this happening and what can I do to stop it from happening?

Comment: Place start code of initially running script (your second file) in a `if __name__ == "__main__"`. Otherwise it will run for any spawned process.

Comment: Worked, thank you!

Comment: Do you know why this is only an issue for the spawn method, but not for fork?

Comment: A subprocess has to be at least in a similar state (optimal: same state) as main process, especially same functions and global constants with same name. Fork basically creates a memory copy for this while spawn has to re-execute the Python code in the subprocess. The "if" prevents the full execution to really run the program.

Comment: Makes sense in hindsight, thanks again for the clarification.